# Adding values depending on text criteria

Tags: vba, excel

First ill show my sample table: 
[image]

This is a project for an insurance agency and i want to be able to calculate the commissions per policy.

I created a SUMIF formula on column F that says

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,$A:$A,A2,$C:$C,C2)
```

This adds the values on column E if values on C an A match. Now i realized that what i want is a little more complicated.

I need a formula that would ADD the values on E if first they match on column A, then the tricky part is on column C where usually values wont match.

I want to add the values from E on F Starting from the type that says either NEW Policy or RENEWAL policy. so if it says "Policy endorsement" it will add these field with all the previous fields that match column A and are in between the date on that field and the nearest(going to the past) Renewal or New Policy commission field.

if it sounds a bit confusing ill explain below:

As i said, This is a project for an insurance agency and i want to be able to calculate the commissions per policy.

Policies renew every year and they keep the same POLICY NUMBER. the only way we know that is a different term is by looking at the TYPE and EFFECTIVE DATE. If we see ABIGAIL we notice that there is 2 different dates (theyre exactly a year apart) and the type says "new policy" for when we first placed the client on this carrier and Renewal Policy when the term restarted on a new policy that still has the same policy number.

Some Policies get changes done in the middle of the term, like SERGIO, who had an increase of 45.51 before the renewal.

I want values to update starting from the earliest renewal or new policy row.

something like this:

[image]

I placed the clearest example with abigail. Please let me know if you have any questions.

I am looking for either a regular Excel Formula or the VBA code to get this done. Either will work for me.

Comment: Shouldn't all of your Policies begin from **New Policy**?

Comment: Well yeah. however some policies are as old as 6 years. and we were not getting digital reports by then. We decided we were just going to back track one year.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it through through VBA by proper sorting and then by cumulative adding.

Something like this:

```
Sub calcComm()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, lastrow As Long, ttl As Double
    lastrow = Cells(ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastrow & ":E" & 2)
    rng1.Sort Columns(3)
    rng1.Sort Columns(1)
    rng1.Sort Columns(2)
    Set rng3 = rng1.Cells(1)
    For Each rng2 In rng1.Columns(1).Cells
        If rng2 = rng3.Cells(1) And (ttl = 0 Or (rng2.Offset(0, 3) <> "New Policy" And rng2.Offset(0, 3) <> "Renewal Policy")) Then
            ttl = ttl + rng2.Offset(0, 4)
            Set rng3 = Range(rng3.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
        Else
            For Each rng4 In rng3
                rng4.Offset(0, 5) = ttl
            Next
            Set rng3 = rng2
            ttl = rng2.Offset(0, 4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```